# libxml2 memory consumption

Tags: c, memory-management, libxml2

I am using libxml2 to parse a xml file and feed it with strings from a csv file based on a match. My device has 512 mb of ram which has around 286 mb left at the start of the parsing routine. In the parsing routine it eats up all the space and ultimately kills the application. I could zero down to the exact loop where memory is consumed in chunks with the iterations.

Here is the code :

```
xmlInitParser();
xmlDocPtr pDoc = xmlParseFile(file_name_path);  

if (pDoc == NULL){
printf("Error : Failed to open file\n");}
else{
xmlXPathContextPtr xPathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(pDoc);
xmlChar *pSrcExpression = (xmlChar*)"/TS/context/message/source";
xmlChar *pTransExpression = (xmlChar*)"/TS/context/message/translation";
xmlXPathObjectPtr pResultingXPathSrcObject =  xmlXPathEvalExpression(pSrcExpression, xPathCtx);
xmlXPathObjectPtr pResultingXPathTransObject = xmlXPathEvalExpression(pTransExpression, xPathCtx);

if (pResultingXPathSrcObject && pResultingXPathTransObject)
{                   
    xmlNodeSetPtr pNodeSrcSet = pResultingXPathSrcObject->nodesetval;
    xmlNodeSetPtr pNodeTransSet = pResultingXPathTransObject->nodesetval;
    
    FILE *stream = fopen (csv_file_name_path , "r");
    if(stream == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error : Failed to open csv file\n");                        
    }
    else
    {
        char line[1024];
        int lineCount = 0;

        while (fgets (line, 1024, stream))
        {
            lineCount++;
            char * tmpSrc = strdup(line);                           
            if(strlen(tmpSrc) > MAX_CHARACTERS_IN_A_LINE_IN_CSV)
            {                               
                free(tmpSrc);
                break;
            }
            char * src = strtok(tmpSrc, ";");                           
            if(src == NULL)
            {                               
                free(tmpSrc);
                break;
            }
            char* trans = strtok(NULL, ";");                            
            if(trans == NULL)
            {
                trans = "\0";
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < pNodeSrcSet->nodeNr; ++i)
            {
                xmlNodePtr pSrcNode = pNodeSrcSet->nodeTab[i];
                char * sourceStr = xmlNodeGetContent(pSrcNode);                             
                if(!strcmp(sourceStr, src)){                                    
                    xmlNodePtr pTransNode = pNodeTransSet->nodeTab[i];
                    if(trans[0] == '\0'){
                        sourceStr = xmlEncodeEntitiesReentrant(pTransNode, sourceStr);
                        xmlNodeSetContent(pTransNode, sourceStr);                                       
                    }
                    else{
                        trans = xmlEncodeEntitiesReentrant(pTransNode, trans);
                        xmlNodeSetContent(pTransNode, trans);                                       
                    }
                }
            }
            free(tmpSrc);
        }
        xmlXPathFreeObject(pResultingXPathSrcObject);
        xmlXPathFreeObject(pResultingXPathTransObject);             

        fclose(stream);                     
        xmlSaveFileEnc(file_name_path, pDoc, "UTF-8");              
    }
}
xmlXPathFreeContext(xPathCtx);
xmlFreeDoc(pDoc);
xmlCleanupParser();}
```

The while loop is where memory start dropping.

I am reading the csv line by line so should not have any memory impact. The xmlPath structures is what I am not sure about. Read they mark the objects for free but do not return it back to the system. But here I am confused as the structures (xmlXPathObjectPtr) and  extraction of the NodeSet (xmlNodeSetPtr ) happen prior to the loop. Then what memory allocation is left to be done in the loop where I move to the nodeTab and compare.

Please help me with your suggestions and if there is something wrong here and if there is any alternate way to achieve it.

Comment: You can use valgrind to track down memory leaks.

Comment: does `xmlNodeGetContent(pSrcNode);` allocate memory? I don't see this getting freed: `char * sourceStr`

Comment: Why `char * tmpSrc = strdup(line);`? There's no need to preserve the contents of `line`, so no need to duplicate it.

Comment: @infinitezero : thanks. The problem was as you pointed out. sourceStr was the leak. I did not run valgrind, however I ran coverity which reported xmlXPathObjectPtr objects as leaks. This i had freed using xmlXPathFreeObject so was suspecting if it these xml api was not doing the job. Do you think Valgrind is superior in reporting such issues or it would have behaved the same as coverity?

Comment: @Some programmer dude : Agreed this duplication is not required.